# openssl s_client Error: verify error:num=2:unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, vpn

I need to connect to some `https://website.com`. So, the site is available via VPN. I'm connected to the VPN and I can open the site in browser.

I've downloaded certificates from browser:

[image]

Then I `cat` both file into one `certificate.pem`

But when I'm trying to execute command

```
openssl s_client -connect website.com:443 -CAfile /path/to/certificate.pem
```

When I execute it in a terminal I have an error.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify error:num=2:unable to get issuer certificate
issuer= /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=AU/ST=Wales/L=Place/O=Company 
Ltd/OU=D&D/CN=website.com 
i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=AU/ST=Wales/L=Place/O=Company 
Ltd/OU=D&D/CN=website.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2034 bytes and written 328 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID:     1533BA958D51B9FEAE4C3534F4A417A5896ED17DCAAE83E89E6C2A7F615A583A
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 5CF  D4ACA242B602AAFSDF1234X23E99BD4C62862888947FACFF0E7503BA34C2DD0EC193FA525204A539
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1509781851
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Answer (score 10):

`openssl` historically and by default validates a certificate chain only if it ends at a **root**. Having the server aka end-entity or leaf cert in the truststore is useless, and the intermediate(s) *should not* be needed because RFCs require the server to send it(them), but your server is apparently defective or misconfigured because it does not. Thus for your server having the intermediate *and root*, but *not* the server cert, in the file used for `-CAfile` will work, assuming they are in PEM format.

**Alternatively,** recent (and supported) releases 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 add an **option `-partial_chain`**. If specified, this validates if the truststore has any anchor, not just a root. For your server, having *either* the server cert *or* the intermediate in the file used for `-CAfile` is sufficient, again in PEM format.

These cases are described on the man page for verify(1) which is referenced from the man page for s_client(1). Some systems may make the section 1ssl or similar, and if your system is not properly installed or is Windows, they are [on the web here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html).

---

Remember that `openssl` historically and by default does not check the server *name* in the cert. 1.1.0 has new options `-verify_name` and `-verify_hostname` that do so. These are described on the man page for verify and referenced on that for s_client.

Also remember that many servers, though apparently not yours, now use Server Name Indication (SNI) extension to support multiple 'virtual' hosts with different certificates, and will either give a wrong cert or reject or fail the connection if SNI is missing. `openssl s_client` does not send SNI by default, but the option `-servername` does so; this is described on the man page. Update: OpenSSL 1.1.1 in 2018 `s_client` now *does* send SNI by default.

In general looking at the man pages for a program tells you useful information about how the program works and how to use it, and is recommended.
Especially since this is not a programming or development question, and really off-topic for StackOverflow; I would try to propose migration to SuperUser or ServerFault, but they already have numerous dupes.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that openssl is looking for the issuer certificate with the subject `"/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA"` but it is not provided in the file /path/to/certificate.pem. Suggest to run `"openssl x509 -in /path/to/certificate.pem -text"` to see the subject of the certificate in this file - should be different from the requested one.

Comment: OP already described in Q which certs they put in this file, but if it were unknown your command only displays the first one not all of them. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366898/generate-hpkp-fingerprints-for-all-certificate-chain/ including links to several other Qs including SO.